# „Tail“ in der Statistik

Tags: english-to-german, mathematics

Im Englischen gibt es *tail* für die beiden Enden einer Wahrscheinlichkeitsverteilung. Gibt es dafür eine Übersetzung?

Z. B.:

> The probability distribution has a long tail.

Wenn ich das wörtlich übersetze, ist es schon fast etwas obszön.

Comment: Tja, das ist eben so, z.B. (keine Übersetzung Deines Satzes) _"Die Verteilung hat einen dicken Schwanz"_.

Comment: Der Begriff "tail" ist auch im Englischen nicht frei von obszönen Konnotationen (es sind allerdings andere als beim deutschen "Schwanz").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich weiß nicht, ob es in der deutschsprachigen Mathematik tatsächlich üblich ist, aber mindestens umgangssprachlich käme *Ausläufer* infrage, evtl. auch *Ende*.

> - *Die Wahrscheinlichtkeitsverteilung hat lange Ausläufer auf beiden Seiten.*
> - *Die Enden der Wahrscheinlichtkeitsverteilung fallen flach ab.*

Das sind beides angebotene Übersetzungen für [*tail* bei Dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=tail), aber ohne speziellen Verwendungshinweis.

Comment: Es geht hier um die *mathematische Fachsprache*, nicht um _mögliche_ umgangssprachliche Übersetzungen.

Comment: Ich weiss nicht ob "Ausläufer" üblich ist, aber "fallen flach ab" ist sicher eine gute Beschreibung und umgeht das Problem elegant.

Comment: @Karl Das gewünschte Level an Fachsprachlichkeit geht aus der Frage nicht direkt hervor.

Comment: Kann "Wahrscheinlichkeitsverteilung" überhaupt umgangssprachlich eingesetzt werden?

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Schulunterricht?

Comment: Naja, Schule ist ja gerade dazu gedacht, Fachsprache beizubringen. Wenn dort einmal das Niveau von _Wahrscheinlichkeitsverteilungen_ erreicht ist, wird das hoffentlich nicht in Umgangssprache eingebettet sein. Abgesehen davon benutze ich "Enden" tatsächlich fachsprachlich (bin aber kein Mathematiker, "nur" Informatiker :P) für die tails, die Antwort muss also gar nicht falsch sein. Ich stör mich bezüglich Deiner Antwort auch nur daran, dass die Q eigentlich nicht danach klingt, dass nach Umgangssprache gefragt wurde. Andererseits sagt das Grüne Häkchen, dass ich falsch liege.

Comment: @Crissov, da Du ja nachlegen mußt, Deinen beiden Sätze  sind fachsprachlich -- bin Mathematiker in W.-Theorie -- IMHO daneben. Fachsprache ist eben Fachsprache und da werden Dinge eben anders artikuliert als in der Umgangssprache.

Answer (score 4):

In der Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie ist der Begriff *Schwanz* durchaus üblich, siehe z. B. Klenke: *Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie*.

Comment: Das ist gut zu Wissen. Da es hier um das Abstract einer Doktorarbeit geht, werde ich "Schwanz" aber trotzdem lieber vermeiden. Die wenigsten Leser werden mit deutscher Statistik-Literatur vertraut sein und ich möchte ungern jemand vor den Kopf stossen.

Comment: @Stefan Klar; Deine Entscheidung.